# Changing textarea placeholder text based on PHP if condition

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this textarea (in a form) echo'd:

```
<textarea id='textarea' name='msg' rows='2' maxlength='255' cols='80' placeholder=' Share a thought...'></textarea>
```

When the form's submit button is clicked, I want it to check if the textarea is empty, and if it is, I want it to change the textarea's placeholder text.

So, something like...

```
$post_msg = htmlentities(strip_tags(@$_POST['msg']));
if ($post_msg == ""){
   echo "<textarea id='textarea' name='msg' rows='2' maxlength='255' cols='80' placeholder=' please enter some text...'></textarea>";
} else {
  // if textarea has text, then execute INSERT query
}
```

But I obviously cannot put the above statement in the echo the textarea is found in, because, the textarea will always be empty when the page is loaded.

How do I change the placeholder text (and color to red) if the submit button is pressed and textarea is empty?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) {
        if( empty( htmlentities( strip_tags( $_POST['msg'] ) ) ) {
            // Output updated textarea (with color, etc.)
        } else {
            // Insert
        }
    } else {
        // Output default textarea
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will this
**PHP** code

```
if(isset($_POST['button'])){//when button have pressed
if(empty($_POST['msg'])){//if msg is not empty 
    $msg = 'please enter some text...';
}
else{//msg is posted msg
    $msg = $_POST['msg'];
}
$field1 = $_POST['field1'];)//another fields red
```